# Designing a database without knowing the details of the data?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

Are there cases where database designers are not allowed to know the details of the data?  I am looking for real-world examples to learn from — please.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the 'details of the data'. Consider handling credit cards. You need to understand how credit cards will be manipulated, and the general characteristics of the data to be stored, and how credit card numbers are checked for validity (and the legal constraints on who can see what, and how the numbers must be stored encrypted, etc). However, you can't expect to be given live credit card data to work with — that would be silly on the part of the company employing you. Generally, if the database designer does not understand the data, the database will be unusable.

Comment: Yes, lots of them. You just use fake data in your dev environment like you normally would anyway.

Comment: I dont think this is a bad question, maybe poorly worded!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help but tell a story about database nightmares.  One of the worst was when Amazon was first growing.  Initially they only sold books, then expanded to music, and then to many other things.

For a period of about two years, Amazon would announce a new market every two or three months -- children's clothing, housewares, garden supplies, food, and so on.  The database folks were tasked with developing and supporting the systems for the product lines.  However, Amazon considered the new product announcements to be highly, highly secret.

In particular, the data warehouse people would be kept further from the loop.  Sometimes, they would find out about a new line of business by reading news -- and then have to support it in the data warehouse.

So, they had to develop a flexible database to meet unannounced business needs.

In any business environment, there are new needs that arise.  I would suggest a book such as Ralph Kimball's "Data Warehouse Toolkit" for more background on how to develop a fairly robust system.

Comment: @ErikE . . . I cannot read the link you suggest (it takes me to an error page).  My interest is much less in *who* downvotes me than in *why*.  I just find it rude to downvote or vote-to-close without providing feedback.  As a rule, I comment first, threaten to downvote, and sometimes carry through.

Comment: @ErikE . . . Interesting exchanges.  Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: You are welcome. I always prefer to be told when I'm doing something wrong--even if it's not true, I want to understand. I am deleting now.

Comment: P.S. search for your last name there. Also, scan the history backward for questions that you recognize... it may go back some days?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working at a company that stores very private personal information. I am not allowed access to the production database. For our development and test environments, we replace all names, addresses, and other personal information with randomly generated information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  I've often seen databases allow for custom data to be defined by the user.  The basic approach is to design a meta data system for your database.  Then allow entities associations with custom fields.  You wouldn't want to do this for all your data, otherwise you'll just end up with a database in a database, but for dynamically adding a number of custom fields this approach works well.